# JTable - Filter data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablesorter

I'm trying to filter a JTable but the results are not as expected.

Below is the JTable with the added elements (I'm using MySQL to store the Data)

[JTable with contents - Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igxtv.png)

When I try to filter the list for someone specific, I do not get the data from the table. For example, I search for "Ana" and nothing appears.

[Search results for "Ana" - Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFFJU.png)

If I try to search using some "numbers", like the salary, I get the right result but the ID is not right. Pictures to clarify the issue below.

[Wrong ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2DJA.png)
[Right ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHX47.png)

The Code to generate the ArrayList with the employees :

```
public static ArrayList<Angajat> listaAngajati() {
        ArrayList<Angajat> listaAngajati = new ArrayList<>();
        try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/angajati", "root", "***");) {

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeQuery("select * from angajati");
            ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
            Angajat angajat;
            while (rs.next()) {
                angajat = new Angajat(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("nume"), rs.getString("prenume"), rs.getInt("varsta"), rs.getString("adresa"), rs.getDouble("salariu"));
                listaAngajati.add(angajat);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in database connection: \n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return listaAngajati;
    }

    public static void arataAngajati() {
        ArrayList<Angajat> arataAngajati = listaAngajati();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tabelangajati.getModel();
        Object[] rand = new Object[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < arataAngajati.size(); i++) {
            rand[0] = arataAngajati.get(i).getID();
            rand[1] = arataAngajati.get(i).getNume();
            rand[2] = arataAngajati.get(i).getPrenume();
            rand[3] = arataAngajati.get(i).getVarsta();
            rand[4] = arataAngajati.get(i).getAdresa();
            rand[5] = arataAngajati.get(i).getSalariu();
            model.addRow(rand);

        }

    }
```

Code to filter the JTable

```
private void cautaInTabelKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
        DefaultTableModel tabel = (DefaultTableModel) tabelangajati.getModel();
        String query = cautaInTabel.getText().toLowerCase();
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sort = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(tabel);
        tabelangajati.setRowSorter(sort);

        sort.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query));

    }
```

**Question** : How can I modify the code so when I try to search for a an employee using his name to get the right result (not like now - **no results**) and when trying to modify the employee data, to get the right ID as shown in the JTable (example in the pictures above) ?

## EDIT

In order to filter the data from the table accordingly I had to use

```
sort.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + query));
```

When I was filtering the table, only the view modified and not the values from the row (Even if I saw the values from the row 3 and values on the backend where from the row 1). I managed to modify the following row and the table works perfectly.

From :

```
int row = tabelangajati.getSelectedRow();
```

To :

```
int row = tabelangajati.convertRowIndexToModel(tabelangajati.getSelectedRow());
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your problem and debug your code. Please don't post your complete code, but rather create a small runnable class which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example. I would guess you are building the regexFilter incorrectly. You appear to be setting the query for lower case characters but your data contains upper case characters so you never have a match.

Comment: You have a problem where you are adding the same object array to the model each iteration. Move the `Object[] rand = new Object[6];` statement inside the for loop. Also, just make us a [MCVE] as already indicated. Hard to see what your problem actually is with the fragments we're seeing.